# How to get video url using youtube api v3

Tags: video, youtube-api

How to get video url by passing video id to `videos.list()` method. It gives video list response and by getting list of video or a single video, it has `id` and other field detail in item collection but there is no info of url like image url for thumbnail in thumbnail collection also please help me to identify that is it possible to get url like this by using youtube api?

```
https://r20---sn-q4f7dnsz.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?mime=video/mp4&key=yt5&expire=1440809348&id=o-ACYc5acY4hYiU3FOucV1okTW8kIeftUuSdZaFLDCv8K6&itag=18&fexp=9408211,9408710,9409069,9409172,9412843,9415365,9415436,9415485,9416023,9416126,9416330,9416575,9416729,9416903,9417707,9418153,9418448,9419501,9419542,9419817,9419832,9420021&sparams=dur,id,ip,ipbits,itag,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,ratebypass,requiressl,source,upn,expire&lmt=1439891155727126&sver=3&ip=107.178.194.92&signature=302D3DDB5B55826188CF675A3DEB70BA213DD550.6B7739E471EFF3A5A8DC69D9288955D4BBDC49C4&ms=au&source=youtube&ratebypass=yes&mv=m&ipbits=0&pl=26&dur=627.890&mn=sn-q4f7dnsz&mt=1440787710&mm=31&requiressl=yes&upn=SVqUiXueXZs&signature=178.162.216.36
```

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: Where did you get this code/link?

Comment: @jonmrich First of all thanks, i have tried this code...

'var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                ApiKey = "xyz",
                ApplicationName = "abc"
            });    

var vidstream = youtubeService.Videos.List("snippet");
            vidstream.Id = id;
  VideoListResponse ser=vidstream.Execute();
            List<Video> vid = ser.Items.ToList();
return vid;

Comment: @Mardzis i get this link in inspect element of a video tag on another video sharing website,which is also using youtube api

Answer (score 2):

So you have the ID of a video, and you need the link to YouTube to watch that video? you can easily build the URL.

this is what you need: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="put the video's id here"

example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CMdHDHEuOUE

Comment: i have tried it,but the problem is that direct youtube url is blocked in my country...so thats why i can not use this youtube url,i want url like that,i have mwntion in question,is it possible to get the url like taht?

Comment: The link you provided is not working. Where does it come from?
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list here you can find all the info you need about  `videos.list()`, but there's no mention of videos URLs.

Comment: please goto [http://playit.pk/watch?v=a18py61_F_w , press F12 or right click >select inspect element,and search for that video play tag, in its inner HTML u will get multiple source tags for different video formats.

Comment: @Flame2057 lol I'd like to see your answer to this question, smarty pants :D he asked how to build a video url having the ID of a video, I told him.